# Eclipse StatET, matching brackets

Tags: eclipse, r, plugins, parentheses, statet

Does anyone know how I can get Eclipse (w/ StatET) to highlight matching brackets within strings?

For example I have the following in the editor:

```
"this is a a string (asdf)"
```

I would like the matching parenthesis to be highlighted when my cursor is over the other one.

Comment: AFAIK, bracket matching only works for code, not text.

Comment: how does notepad++ do it? it seems to work on text there.

Comment: it seems this must be an option to turn on and off since if i just type my string without the quotes the matching works.. i can just add the quotes later i guess but this is not fun.